# I keep getting Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'n' was corrupted at the end of my program

Tags: c

I am very new to C I keep getting the check failure stated in the tile at the end of the program. I have spent the past two hours looking for an answer. Any help would be appreciated.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <limits.h>
int main()
{
unsigned short int N;
printf("Enter an unsigned short number\n");
scanf("%i",&N);
printf("The value of 2 raised to the %i power is %1.f\n",N, pow(2.,N));
getchar();
return 0;
}
```

Here is what I get for the error

Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'N' was corrupted.

Comment: The error is entirely accurate, with %i you store 32-bits in a 16-bit variable.  That corrupts the stack.

Comment: when writing/posting code, please indent the code, for human readability

Answer (score 2):

The problem is on this line:

```
scanf("%i",&N);
```

The format token `%i` means `int`, but you've declared `N` to be an `unsigned short int`. A short int is smaller than a regular int (typically 2 bytes vs 4), so when `scanf` writes to `N`, it tries to write a whole integer instead of a short. This means that it writes the two bytes for the short, *then two more bytes afterward*, which is why you're corrupting the stack "around the variable N".

To fix this problem, use this line instead:

```
scanf("%hu",&N);
```

The `%h` means "half" (half of an `int` is a `short`), and the `u` means unsigned.